# how did you install rdkit on heroku

Tags: heroku, installation, rdkit

I need to install rdkit in heroku for my heroku app to run. I installed rdkit locally in my laptop by using

`sudo apt-get install python-rdkit`.

But when I generated the requirements file using `pip freeze` , the generated file is not showing the rdkit. And `pip install python-rdkit` or `pip install rdkit` are not working. Can any one please tell me how can I install rdkit on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda and

```
conda install -c rdkit rdkit
```

as per instructions here: http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was asked about seven years ago, I recently faced the same problem doing this. So I am writing the process I followed and succeeded, if it helps anyone.

First add a `conda buildpack` on your heroku project, because `rdkit` is not available on `pip`. I have used [this](https://github.com/pl31/heroku-buildpack-conda) buildpack for my rdkit project before. The official `conda` buildpack is deprecated and it does not support python3. If you use heroku cli then just insert this command to use this buildpack:

```sh
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/pl31/heroku-buildpack-conda
```

This buildpack needs an `environment.yml` file for `conda` packages instead of `requirements.txt` file which we use for `pip`. To create the file from your virtual environment use this command: `conda env export > environment.yml`. This command also lists all the `pip` packages so you won't need separate file for `pip` packages. If you want to create a virtualenv from this file just run `conda env create -f environment.yml`.

Once this file is there, you can deploy your project as you would do for any other python projects.